# How to turn a file into a Nokogiri::XML object?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a sample XML file (let's call it `example.xml` for the sake of this question) and want to turn it into a Nokogiri object.

According to documentation and lots of other online sources, this should work:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("example.txt"))
```

But the value of `xml.to_xml` is only:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
```

In other words, it's ignoring the rest of the file. There are many tags afterwards and none of them are in the `xml` object.

How do I get Nokogiri to get all the tags?

Here's the XML I'm using:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Document>
    <Test>Test</Test>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to parse an invalid XML doc.

This can be fixed by removing the spaces in the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Test>Test</Test>
</Document>
```

---

### How I figured this out

By default, when Nokogiri has errors parsing a document it populates an `errors` array.

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("example.txt"))
p xml.errors
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: xmlParsePI : no target name>, #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found>]
```

You can also configure Nokogiri to raise an exception of it has parsing errors:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("example.txt")) do |config|
  config.strict
end
```

Both of these cases show that there were issues parsing the document